# 0x API Quote estimatedPriceImpact unit

Tags: 0x

What is a unit of estimatedPriceImpact, as the field isn't added to the documentation? I'm asking because we want to display the percentage
For example, I receive from API 0,0072, so what should I display for percentage? 0,72% or 0,0072%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that calculates the estimatedPriceImpact is founded here: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/blob/63fd378c3fd198fd1760cd684763956defccfb55/src/services/swap_service.ts#L99, which then is named estimatedPriceImpact here: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/blob/63fd378c3fd198fd1760cd684763956defccfb55/src/services/swap_service.ts#L482 As you can see according to the documentation presented on the method the returned result is on percent so 0,0072 should be 0,0072%